# Are CSS3 ::before and ::after pseudo elements supported by IE9 or not?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-selectors, pseudo-element

On [this MS compatibility table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says, IE9 does not support pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`, but when I try it seems it does... see [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/itafek/edit#javascript,html,live)

Am I doing something wrong? I thought `::before` and `::after` would be nice tools to hide stuff from IE9, when in fact, they don't.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2 Check the **"Known issues"** tab below the chart.

Comment: @inhan: It doesn't say anything about IE9.

Comment: @BoltClock my bad, sorry. http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter

Comment: @inhan: Nothing about IE9 in there either...

Comment: @BoltClock look at the IE column and see the version numbers. Shall I post a screenshot?

Comment: @inhan: Oh, I thought you meant to look at the Known Issues tab. My bad this time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The CSS2 pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`, with the traditional single-colon notation, are supported by IE8 and later. They are not new to CSS3.

The double-colon notation, on the other hand, is [new to CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements). IE9 *does* support this new notation for [`::before`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc304078.aspx) and [`::after`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304076.aspx), and likewise for the CSS1 pseudo-elements [`::first-line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530754.aspx) and [`::first-letter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530753.aspx). Going forward, however, no new pseudo-element may use the single colon syntax, and browsers (including IE) are expected to support the double colon syntax for all pseudo-elements.

I have no clue why that table says IE9 doesn't support the new pseudo-element syntax, because it certainly does according to the docs for the individual selectors linked above, and your test case. As well as, of course, this answer.

Comment: There's a difference between CSS2.1 and CSS3 and the colon and double colon. The double colon is used in CSS3 for pseudo-elements while the single colon is only used for pseudo-selectors. In CSS2.1, the single colon represented both.

Comment: @Rob: "while the single colon is only used for **pseudo-classes**." Double colons and single colons were introduced *precisely because* people were munging both pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes together into a confusing umbrella term called "pseudo-selectors" while the single colon was being used to represent them both.

Answer (score 5):

IE 9 supports the notations `::after` and `::before` (with two colons) in “standards mode”. In “quirks mode”, it does not. This can be tested e.g. as follows:

```
<style>
p::after  {  
  content: "***AFTER***";  
} 
</style>
<p>Hello world
```

Here the CSS rule is ignored, because IE 9 goes to quirks mode. But if you add the following line at the very start, IE 9 goes to standards mode and the CSS rule takes effect:

```
<!doctype html>
```

It is common in IE 9 that in [quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), new CSS features (most features that are neither in CSS 2.1 or in the IE legacy) are not supported. In quirks mode, IE 9 does not support the old one-colon notations  `:after` and `:before` either. It supports them (but not the two-colon versions) in “IE 8 mode”, which you can select in developer tools (F12) manually, in the “document mode” menu, or at document level using the tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct: because IE acts similarly to version 4 or 5 of itself when in quirks mode as stated in your article, anything that that version didn't support will be missing in quirks mode in any later version of IE. This means `:after` and `:before` in both the old and new notations won't be supported in quirks mode on any version of IE.

Comment: Note also that compatibility mode in IE8+ is significantly different to quirks mode in that compatibility mode emulates IE7, whereas quirks mode emulates IE4/5.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks, I stand corrected and will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted from http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors

> **CSS3 pseudo-element double colon syntax**
>   Please note that the new CSS3
>   way of writing pseudo-elements is to use a double colon, eg a::after {
>   ... }, to set them apart from pseudo-classes. You may see this
>   sometimes in CSS. CSS3 however also still allows for single colon
>   pseudo-elements, for the sake of backwards compatibility, and we would
>   advise that you stick with this syntax for the time being.