# li:last-child doesn't seem to work in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

Below is my html structure

```
<div class="footerMenu">
   <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Feedback</li>
     <li>Contact us</li>        
   </ul>            
</div>
```

But

```
.footerMenu li:last-child { }
```

selector doesn't seem to work in IE8. But http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx tells that the pseudo-selector is suppported.Any help on this!

Comment: I am 99% sure it is not supported

Comment: Have you tried .footerMenu li: { something drastic; } just to see if this much is working?

Comment: No, it actually doesn't. It says right there that it's supported in IE9 and later.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293369/using-last-child-in-css

Comment: yes just .footerMenu li{} works

Comment: yup correct last-child is not but strangely first-child is ..

Answer (score 27):

You read it wrong. It says that it's **not** supported in IE8:

[image]

If you were looking at `:first-child`, which does have support in IE7 and IE8, and thinking that the same applies to `:last-child`... surprise! It doesn't.

`:first-child` is a CSS2 selector, but `:last-child` was only introduced in CSS3, so since Microsoft was only aiming for CSS2.1 compliance with IE8, they likely didn't bother about `:last-child` until post-IE8.

If you know you will only have four `li` elements, then you should be able to use adjacent sibling selectors to reach the fourth `li`:

```
.footerMenu li:first-child + li + li + li
```

Comment: yup i assumed that since first was there even last would be also supported. thanks for info.

Comment: Incidentally, what the table **does** get wrong is IE9's support for CSS3's double-colon notation for CSS1/2 pseudo-elements (while oddly enough it gets it right for CSS3 pseudo-elements): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-after-and-before-pseudo-elements-rendered-by-ie9/7157425#7157425

Answer (score 2):

To build on the other guys answers, an alternative could be to use javascript to fill the gaps, selectivizr is a good example of adding last-child support.

http://selectivizr.com/

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided shows that it isn't supported for IE8... IE9+ only. Googling last-child IE8 brings up a whole host of similar queries.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that? `:first-child` is supported back to IE7, but `:last-child` is IE9 and later.

[image: No, it doesn't.]

(Headers moved down for your convenience)

Comment: sorry for my mistake..i overlooked it!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct that IE8 doesn't support last-child. However, to solve your particular problem, you could either a) manually add a class to the last `<li>` or b) as this is a menu, and these will presumably have links inside them, target the last link with an attribute selector, which does work in IE8. Something like

```
.footermenu a[href="contact.html"] { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like that:

```
.footerMenu li {background-color: expression(this.previousSibling==null?'red':'green');}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but...there is a simple way to do it:

Just in the li you want the change do this:

`<li style="yourstyle;">`...`</li>`