# Make first-child and last-child work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selectivizr

In my project, I am trying to make the below css work in IE8 using [selectivizr](https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/blob/master/selectivizr.js)

```
thead>tr:first-child>th:last-child {
    color: red;
}
tbody>tr:first-child>td:last-child {
    color: red;
}
```

---

As described in [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) website, I added the below code in "*External Resources*" of [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/M7tBr/).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/blob/master/selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

Still I can't make `first-child` and `last-child` pseudo selectors work in IE8.

I am switching all the versions of IE into IE8 using the following code. (*just for information*).

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Comment: It looks like [`last-child`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is implemented in IE>=9, hence it breaks the whole rule where it's included.

Comment: @Teemu I am including the above selectivizr script only to IE8< using conditional css.

Comment: Right now I have two doubts in my mind. **1**) whether I included the script tags correctly in jsfiddle?  **2**) what should be inside `[fallback css]`?

Comment: you can delete the fallback. It's for when JS is disabled in the browser.
Your accepted answer is not an answer to this question: why selectivizr doesn not work with jQuery 1.10.x ?
You should make that clear because i came here searching for this problem and the accepted answer is not an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the following as I have fixed columns

```
thead>tr:first-child>th:first-child+th+th+th {
    color: red;
}
tbody>tr:first-child>td:first-child+td+td+td {
    color: red;
}
```

I did the above as `first-child` supports IE8 but not `last-child`.

It is working properly in IE8.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10800587/1577396)

Anyway, I still don't know how to use **selectivizr** in project.

Answer (score 2):

This selectors does not support in IE8, so you can assign id or special class to first and last elements. For example:

```
<tr class="thisSection">
     <td class="customClass firstTD">1</td>
     <td class="customClass">2</td>
     <td class="customClass">3</td>
     <td class="customClass lastTD">4</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't go with an alternative. I am in a state that I need to make those pseudo selectors work properly in IE8. even if I need to include JS libraries. This is not at all option for me in my current project.

Comment: @Mr_Green Why do you ***need*** to have these pseudo-selectors working in IE8? Why can't you use JavaScript to add these classes for for last child elements?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I can't add code dynamically. though I can include libraries. It is very big project and adding code dynamically will be too much risky. Anyway, I solved it going through one of Boltclock's solution.