# JavaScript which is meant for PrimeFaces data table does not work after the data table is updated by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

The following JavaScript function hides the sort arrow (up or down) from the `<p:dataTable>` header whose id is `discountStartDate`

```
function removeSortableIconCSS()
{
    $('#form\\:dataTable\\:discountStartDate .ui-sortable-column-icon').css({"display":"none"});
}

$(document).ready(removeSortableIconCSS);
```

It turns the column header from,

[image]

to the following.

[image]

The sort arrow is removed.

---

After updating the `<p:dataTable>` using the following `<p:commandButton>`,

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" update="dataTable"/>

<p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" actionListener="#{bean.insert}" value="Save"
oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed) {updateTable();} removeSortableIconCSS();"/>

<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row" value="#{discountManagedBean}"...>
    ...

    <p:column id="discountStartDate" sortBy="#{row.discountStartDate}" width="200">

    ...

    </p:column>

    ...

</p:dataTable>
```

however, it doesn't work even though the JavaScript function `removeSortableIconCSS()` is invoked on the `oncomplete` event of `<p:commandButton>` and the sort icon appears as in the first image (as soon as the AJAX request is completed and the `<p:dataTable>` is updated).

<sub>It is not an actual requirement. It is just a demonstration of the problem that happens somewhere else and needs to be tackled.</sub>

Comment: I understand that it's not an actual requirement, but this particular case could be solved more easily by just overriding the style in a CSS file.

Comment: Particularly in this case, actually, I need to override the specified class in the last element (which is `<span>`) inside `<th>` (that corresponds to `<p:dataTable>` header. I'm just trying to implement a custom filter that allows users to use `<p:calendar>`). This has been solved by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20224959/1391249) answer but doing so by CSS is not supported by some obscure browsers. This needs to be considered, when it is not supported by Internet explorer as mentioned in that answer.

Comment: Is an error thrown and shown in the console or does the function just complete without hiding the arrow

Comment: @SamNunnally : Seen on Google Chrome. It does not show any error. (**Off topic :** It however, shows a warning, "*`event.returnValue` is deprecated. Please use the standard `event.preventDefault()` instead*" but this happens through out the application which is coming from somewhere in PrimeFaces itself).

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `sortBy` attribute of the column in the datatable?

Comment: In case the `sortBy` removal isn't an option: if I had to hazard a guess, `$('#form\\:dataTable\\:discountStartDate .ui-sortable-column-icon')` is probably returning an empty array when the function is called via the `oncomplete` block. Perhaps you could debug why that is occurring.

Comment: @patstuart : Then sorting is disabled which is necessary. It is just a custom **filter** and does not include custom **sorting** function anymore.

Comment: If you need to sort the set, but don't want the user to be able to do so, then you can just sort the list on the client side.

Comment: *server side, not client side

Comment: I guess Primefaces does some extra work in frontend after `oncomplete`. I've put `$('.ui-sortable-column-icon').css({"display":"none"});` inside `setTimeout` and set it to few seconds. After few seconds arrows disappears again.