# css selectors issue in ie8,9

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-selectors

I have a div class named switch control which has a div class named thumb as child

```
<div class="switch-control">
         <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

and there are css for them called:

```
.switch-control > .thumb
.switch-control > .thumb::before
```

Both css classes are taking affect and used on chrome and firefox, but on IE8,9 the `.switch-control > .thumb` is active and the `.switch-control > .thumb::before` is marked out and not used thus I can't see it taking affect on IE8,9

Why is that and how can I fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing IE8 and IE9 don't support the `:before` pseudoclass, just like older versions of IE only supported the `:hover` pseudoclass on anchor elements when all other major browsers already supported it for all elements.

Comment: actually, if you look it up, it seems like IE8 and IE9 does support :before and :after

Comment: Well, are the two colons you use in your question accurate to the actual stylesheet, and if so have you tried using only one colon there? I don't believe I've ever seen double colons used for pseudoclasses before, so it may be that Chrome and Firefox support it while IE doesn't if that actually is the case.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my css style sheet from .switch-control > .thumb::before to .switch-control > .thumb:before (from double colon to single colon) but all browsers (chrome and IE) still shows double colon. how  come?

Comment: I tested and JAB is right: the double colon notation is not supported by IE (at least IE8; can't test IE9). So what do you mean by "still shows double colon"?

Comment: @JAB: That's because 1) while `:hover` is a [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes), `::before` is not, it's a [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements), therefore: 2) Double colons are not and have never been used by pseudo-classes, only by pseudo-elements as of CSS3. In fact, that syntax was introduced solely to distinguish pseudo-elements from pseudo-classes because people were getting them mixed up.

Comment: @Mr Lister: IE9 supports double colons for pseudo-elements, but only in standards mode. (It doesn't support CSS2 pseudo-elements in quirks mode anyway.)

Comment: @BoltClock: Oh, I wasn't aware of the distinction. Haven't done enough with CSS3, I suppose.

Comment: @JAB: Well like I said, they were getting mixed up by sharing single colons, so they had to introduce the new syntax pretty late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 has a tendency to cross out styles for pseudo-elements for some weird reason, but it does support the CSS3 double-colon notation for all supported pseudo-elements (this includes CSS1 `::first-line` and `::first-letter`, and CSS2 `::before` and `::after`). If your styles aren't working, something else is wrong (there are a number of SO questions to this effect but I have no clue what could be causing the problem).

IE8 does not support the CSS3 double-colon notation for any pseudo-elements, only the single-colon notation that has always traditionally been in use.

If you need to support IE8, you have to use the traditional single-colon notation (which every browser is expected to continue supporting for compatibility reasons):

```
.switch-control > .thumb:before
```

And regarding your comment:

> I have updated my css style sheet from .switch-control > .thumb::before to .switch-control > .thumb:before (from double colon to single colon) but all browsers (chrome and IE) still shows double colon. how come?

As I mentioned, pseudo-elements are now supposed to be prefixed with double colons, with single colons maintained for compatibility. It's simply the new notation that should be used starting from CSS3 selectors and going forward, so when a browser's developer tools encounter a *pseudo-element* rather than a *pseudo-class*, it displays it with double colons if it understands CSS3.

In other words, it's just the browser UI showing it with double colons. It's not altering the code in your stylesheet in any way.

Comment: @JAB: [That is actually a mistake.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-after-and-before-pseudo-elements-rendered-by-ie9/7157425#7157425)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc304078.aspx.