# li::before for IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element

I am using `li::before` to get rid of some content, but this code works in all browsers but not IE8. Why? Do I need a JavaScript solution?

This is my code:

```
.NewsArchive li::before, .NewsSubMenu li::before {
    content: "• ";
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or some other JS framework?

Comment: Should work: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html for ie > 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE8 does not support [CSS3's double-colon notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) for CSS1 and CSS2 pseudo-elements. That notation is only supported by [IE9 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-supported-by-ie9-or-not/7157425#7157425), and other browsers.

If you need IE8 support, you have to use single colons:

```
.NewsArchive li:before, .NewsSubMenu li:before {
    content: "• ";
    display: none !important;
}
```

No need for JavaScript. And you most probably don't need that `!important` either.