# css "::after" class not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, pseudo-element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are CSS3 ::before and ::after pseudo elements supported by IE9 or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-supported-by-ie9-or-not)

I have a wordpress page set up [here](http://jaxmedia.com/projects/). It does use tables, which I know is dumb, but it was the best way to set up the visual layout in the backend as well, so the client could see what they're doing when they edit.

ANYHOO, I have a separator image that displays after each table row, using "tr::after" css. This looks fine in any browser EXCEPT for Internet Explorer, where instead of showing up below the table row, the separator seems to scrunch the second column and squeeze beside it [(image)](http://jaxmedia.com/ie.png)

I can't seem to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: That screenshot is from IE9 - in IE 8 the table looks correct, but the after element just doesn't display at all.

Answer (score 1):

IE 8+ supports the [`:after` pseudo-element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx#pseudoelements) - note the single colon (:)

<strike>according to the above link no IE version (though IE 10 is not in this list) supports the two-colon pseudo element</strike>

**edit:**

IE 9+ supports the two-colon pseudo-element (as @BoltClock mentions [Are CSS3 ::before and ::after pseudo elements supported by IE9 or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-supported-by-ie9-or-not/7157425#7157425))

Comment: [That link is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-supported-by-ie9-or-not/7157425#7157425)

Comment: @BoltClock well that's unfortunate, tends to be a good reference for IE supported styles.

Comment: we'll see if my feedback on that link is heard

Comment: It actually looks the same with the single or double colon - doesn't seem to make a difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

You're only using the CSS3 syntax which was created to distinguish pseudo-elements from pseudo-classes like `:hover` and `:focus`. While the later target *states* of an element, `::after` targets pseudo-elements following the target.

Internet Explorer 8, like other browsers, supports the CSS2 version. Support for the CSS3 syntax wasn't added until Internet Explorer 9. If you want full compatibility, you can provide both, or provide the former CSS2 syntax within an IE8 comment.

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states the following:

> In Windows Internet Explorer 8, as well as later versions of Windows Internet Explorer in IE8 Standards mode, only the one-colon form of this pseudo-element is recognized—that is, :after.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this information, but I don't think this is the reason why it's being displayed the way it is, as I have the same problem even using a single colon.

Comment: @DarrenMiller I went back to your demo, but you appear to have changed it. Can you please link to an example that won't change in the future - a demo using http://jsfiddle.net would be ideal.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I kept trying to fix it and eventually gave up and just completely restructured the page layout.