# li::before not working in IE9

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I have a utility nav set up as an unordered list and I would like to use li::before to insert a pipe "|" symbol between each link in the utility nav.

Here is my utility nav...

```
<div class="horizontalnavlinks">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/ets/">Time & Expense</a></li>
        <li><a href="/intrnl/voffice/TAC/default2.asp">TAC</a></li>
        <li><a href="/people/search/srchframe.asp">Employee Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:intranetfeedback@ch2m.com">Can't Find It?</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here are my styles.

```css
.horizontalnavlinks ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.horizontalnavlinks ul li
{
    display: inline;
}

.horizontalnavlinks li + li::before
{
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

The pipes show up great in Chrome and Safari, but don't show up in IE9. In fact IE9 ignores the enter `.horizontalnavlinks li + li::before` style.

Everything I read says IE supports pseudo styles. What gives?

Comment: Can you please setup a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have a proper doctype declaration (e.g., `<!DOCTYPE html>`) as IE9 running in quirksmode will not support pseudo-elements.

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-supported-by-ie9-or-not) for more details on the use of pseudo-elements in IE9.

Comment: This wouldn't be an either-or situation. Whether you use single or double colons you will always need the doctype to use `:before` and `:after`. At least in IE9.

Comment: @BoltClock My original statement was confusing (I had suggested two possible solutions that were meant to be exclusive). I've updated my answer accordingly.