# Where to display font icons: as a separate element or using existing one?

Tags: css

In a project some icons (from [Icomoon app](http://icomoon.io/)) are added via separate element (e.g `span`), and some are displayed adding particular class to existing one, e.g

```
<span class='icon-archive'></span>
<span class='foo'>some text</span>

<span class='foo icon-archive'>some text</span>
```

The styles are something like this

```
[class*='icon-']:before, .icon:before
  display: inline-block
  font-family: 'foo-glyphs'
  speak: none
  font-size: $icon-font-size
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: normal
  font-variant: normal
  text-transform: none
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased

.icon-archive:before
  content: "\e000"
```

Lately I noticed some problems with vertical alignment - probably because css doesn't have `line-height: 1`

I would like to know which strategy is better (or maybe either of them is good)?

Comment: I prefer version 2 if only to keep my markup as pithy as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends whether the function of your icons is *content* or *presentation*. If the icons are just adding decoration to text (e.g. a floppy disk icon next to a "Save" link etc), I would favour the method using the pseudo-element `:before` (rather than adding a `span` element just for the icon) for a cleaner DOM and better separation of concerns.

However, if the icons are the only way you are presenting the information to the user, you should insert them as `span` elements. A major reason for this is that screen-readers do not respond well to pseudo-elements.

<s>Lastly, if you have to support IE8, you don't have the option of using `:before`, so it's an easy choice in that case!</s> EDIT: This isn't true. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-supported-by-ie9-or-not).

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before IE8 supports `:before`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. :) You're right - IE8 supports the single-colon syntax for pseudo-elements but not the double-colon (CSS3) syntax.