# Does a:after work in IE 9?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out my problem, but still no luck. What I want to know why this css code is not working in IE9?
Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/winresh24/xNLNw/ hope you can help me..

```
#front1 .menu-main .item a{position:relative;}

#front1 .menu-main .item a span{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0);color:#000;-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-o-transition:-o-transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-ms-transition:-ms-transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);transition:transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);display:block}

#front1 .menu-main .item a:after{content:attr(data-text);color:#fff;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;padding-top:4px;top:0;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);-o-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-o-transition:-o-transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-ms-transition:-ms-transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);transition:transform 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);text-align:center;background:#432c75}

#front1 .menu-main .item a:hover span,
#front1 .menu-main .item a.status-active span,
#front1 .menu-main .item.active-parent a span
{-webkit-transition-duration:1s;-moz-transition-duration:1s;-o-transition-duration:1s;-ms-transition-duration:1s;transition-duration:1s;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,-14px,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,-14px,0);-o-transform:translate3d(0,-14px,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,-14px,0);transform:translate3d(0,-14px,0)}

#front1 .menu-main .item a:hover:after,
#front1 .menu-main .item a.status-active:after,
#front1 .menu-main .item.active-parent a:after
{-webkit-transition-duration:1s;-moz-transition-duration:1s;-o-transition-duration:1s;-ms-transition-duration:1s;transition-duration:1s;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}

.no-csstransforms3d #front1 .menu-main .item a span{top:0;-webkit-transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-moz-transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-o-transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-ms-transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1)}

.no-csstransforms3d #front1 .menu-main .item a:after{top:100%;-webkit-transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-moz-transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-o-transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);-ms-transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);transition:top 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);bottom:0}

.no-csstransforms3d #front1 .menu-main .item a:hover span{top:-14px}
.no-csstransforms3d #front1 .menu-main .item a:hover:after{top:0}
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div class="menu-main">
    <ul class="reset">
        <li class="item" id="items"><a href="about.html" data-text="ABOUT US"><span>ABOUT US</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="services.html" data-text="SERVICES" class="itemsa"><span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
        <li class="item" id="item"><a href="mediarelease.html" data-text="MEDIA RELEASE"><span class ="menu">MEDIA RELEASE</span></a></li>      <li class="item" id="item"><a href="businessopportunity.html" data-text="BUSINESS OPPORTUNITY"><span class ="menu">BUSINESS OPPORTUNITY</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="contact.html" data-text="CONTACT US"><span>CONTACT US</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot in IE and Chrome:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: ::after pseudo-element does work, but CSS transitions does not work on IE9. That could be your problem.

Comment: Check your DOCTYPE (As known in IE8 IE9 handle it equal) ...

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent

Comment: It can be seen with a trivial test that `a:after` as such works in IE 9. You need to describe what actually happens and what is wrong with it and to try to isolate the problem (to create a *minimal* case where the problem still appears).

Comment: Answering to your title, yes the pseudo element :after works in IE9. [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-supported-by-ie9-or-not#7157425)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my css?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/winresh24/xNLNw/ here is the jsfiddle....

Comment: can anyone answer this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes after is working in IE9, Prtial in IE8 and not belowIE8.
>
> but you are using **css-transitions** will not work on IE9

[image: css compatibility]

---

[image: css compatibility]