# IE radio button hide not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, radio-button

This piece of code works in Chrome, but the default radio button shows up in IE over the style.

In IE the radio button is not getting hidden. Here is the code.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 15px !important;
  height: 15px !important;
  border: 3px solid #999999 !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
input[type=radio]:hover {

}
input[type=radio]:before {
  content: '' !important;
  display: block !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}
input[type=radio]:checked:before {
  background: #005eb8 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio"  id="a"/>No 1
```

Comment: You can't use pseudo element on single tag elements like `input`, still, Chrome does render it, IE doesn't

Comment: Don't style radio buttons itself because some browsers don't support that. Use some more markup for custom radio- or checkbuttons. Good example here - https://codepen.io/mitchmc/pen/pebIx

Comment: May I know in your version of IE ? IE old bowers doesn't support the Pseudo Elements.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157405/are-css3-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-supported-by-ie9-or-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the code is it use the pseudo on the `input` element.

Pseudo element shouldn't work on single tag element, like `input`, `img` and so on, though Chrome let it anyway

If you set the pseudo on the `label` instead, it will work cross browser

```css
div {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 0 8px -2px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
  background: #005eb8;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rd">
  <label for="r1">Button 1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rd">
  <label for="r2">Button 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment why, on a fully working code snippet?